# Use of "by" before "using"

Tags: prepositions

> 1. Infusion cannula entry sites are anesthetized with
>      1% lidocaine with 1:100,000 epinephrine and small
>      incisions are made **using** a #11 blade.
> 2. Whenever a file is opened **using** fopen function, a
>      file pointer is returned.
> 3. The area selected for developing is cleared **using** bulldozers, either by cutting the trees with a V-
>      cutter or by walking the trees down with the dozer
>      raised about 3 feet off the ground.
> 4. **Using** a screwdriver, remove the four screws
>      holding the cover in place.
> 5. Four specimens each of 38 mm in diameter are cut
>      **using** the appropriate cutter.

In these five sentences **using** has been used in different ways. But **by** has not been used before **using**. Will it be wrong if I use ***by*** before ***using***? Why will it be wrong? If using of **by** in this case is wrong, please tell me when I can use **by using**.

Comment: Why do you think **using** is used different in each example? Its usage means **by means of** / **by way of**.  Replacing **using** with **by using** would not change the meaning or understanding, though in #4 it would be awkward and the sentence should probably be **inverted** to sound natural.

Comment: Just throwing this out for comment: As a native speaker I noticed all of these sentences are written in the third person passive voice except maybe #4. I would be more inclined to use by when writing in a second person active voice, e.g.: You make an incision by using a #11 blade. You obtain a file pointer by using fopen.

Answer (score 2):

Peter's comment is your best answer so far. He said,

> "Why do you think **using** is used differently in each example? Its usage means **by means of / by way of.** Replacing **using** with **by using** would not change the meaning or understanding, though in #4 it would be awkward and the sentence should be **inverted** to sound natural."

It will not be wrong if you say "by using," it just is not necessary in these examples. It's a matter of style and personal preference. By using "by using," you are creating a prepositional phrase. :-)